# API related with XML?

Tags: php, xml, api, pinnacle-cart

Is it done correctly? I am still confused with how api works. I am newbie. I have gone around google to find answers. I followed tutorial and tried to modify it. It is basic one.

I would like to retrieve the images of products which is on sale (mode=hot) for slideshow. I will appreciate the help if you could help me to understand how api shld be done.

**EDIT**
I am trying to pull the images from database in pinnacle cart. so i wanted to list out what it have in xml. **All xml you see below is on source view but not on webpage itself, is it normal? Also when I am trying to show the images on webpage and the images don't appear. I am not sure where I went wrong.**

```
     <Product>
  <Price><![CDATA[695.00000]]></Price>
 <Visible><![CDATA[Yes]]></Visible>
<Taxable><![CDATA[Yes]]></Taxable>
<Weight><![CDATA[0.00]]></Weight>
<UPC><![CDATA[]]></UPC>
<Sku><![CDATA[]]></Sku>
<Title><![CDATA[Necklace]]></Title>
<URL><![CDATA[https://xxxxx/staging/index.php?p=product&amp;id=80]]></URL>
<ThumbnailImageUrl><![CDATA[http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/staging/images/products/thumbs/100040.jpg]]></ThumbnailImageUrl>
<ImageUrl><![CDATA[http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/staging/images/products/100040.jpg]]></ImageUrl>
<Discontinued><![CDATA[No]]></Discontinued>
<Options>    </Options>
<Added><![CDATA[2010-05-12 13:50:00]]></Added>
<ManufaturerName><![CDATA[]]></ManufaturerName>
<Description><![CDATA[<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>]]></Description>
<AmazonId><![CDATA[]]></AmazonId>
<AmazonItemCondition><![CDATA[]]></AmazonItemCondition>
<AmazonIdType><![CDATA[]]></AmazonIdType>
<EbayCategoryId><![CDATA[]]></EbayCategoryId>
<YahooPath><![CDATA[]]></YahooPath>
<GoogleItemCondition><![CDATA[]]></GoogleItemCondition>
<PricegrabberCategory><![CDATA[]]></PricegrabberCategory>
<PricegrabberItemCondition><![CDATA[]]></PricegrabberItemCondition>
<PricegrabberPartNumber><![CDATA[]]></PricegrabberPartNumber>
<InventoryControl><![CDATA[Yes]]></InventoryControl>
<PID><![CDATA[80]]></PID>
<ProductId><![CDATA[100040]]></ProductId>
<Qoh><![CDATA[1]]></Qoh>
<NextagCategory><![CDATA[]]></NextagCategory>
<NextagPartNumber><![CDATA[]]></NextagPartNumber>
<NextagItemCondition><![CDATA[]]></NextagItemCondition>
</Product>
```

My code

```
    <?php
    $shop='www.xxx.com/staging/content/admin/plugins/openapi/index.php?';
    $user = "asd";
    $password = "ad";
    $token = 'token';

    // Assemble the account url
    $url = 'https://'.$shop."username=".$user."&amp;password=".$password."&amp;token=".$token. "&apiType=xml&call=GetProducts&mode=hot";

    // Setup the cURL object
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($l_oCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

    $response=curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $image_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
   **foreach($xml->ThumbnailImageUrl as $thumbs){
echo "<img src=".$thumbs."/>";**
}

    ?>
```

Comment: For one thing, the `&amp;` is the *XML* escaping of `&`. Escaping is required in order to output valid XML, but *not* in providing a URL to cURL. (You're actually sending the parameter `amp;password`, not `password`.)

Comment: @jmort253, @jakenoble, @jensgram -- thanks for your help. It works now. ONE question is how to pull only thumbnail images to be displayed on webpage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SimpleXml` can load remote URLs with `simplexml_load_file` and all libxml bases extensions can be used with a custom [Stream](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php) [Context](https://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.contexts.php). Just create your custom context with [`stream_context_create`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) and then set it with [`libxml_set_streams_context`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-set-streams-context.php). See [Context List and Options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.php)

To generate a URL encoded string, use [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

As for using SimpleXml, please see the [Basic Usage Examples in the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php). You basically just have to traverse to the node and echo it, e.g.

```
echo $sxe->someNode->someOtherNode->ThumbnailImageUrl;
```

Comment: @gordon - thanks for simplexml info! appreciated everyone's help :)

Comment: how to get multiple variables like thumbnailimageurl, url of products, etc? i am sorry but i read through the examples..but i am not sure if i can use foreach for all variables?

Comment: @Josephine Have a look at Example 4. Non Unique elements can be foreached or accessed like an array, e.g. $sxe->nonUniqueElement[n]. Also check out http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nke7SmhDh-M

Comment: @gordon -- i followed the example but seems like I don't get it right? see the edit above

Comment: @Josephine the root node will be omitted. Try `foreach($sxe->ThumbnailImageUrl as $thumbnails){`. Note that there is only one element of that name, so you can just as well just do `echo $sxe->ThumbnailImageUrl`

Comment: @gordon, ahh. i am sorry but one more question - is it possible to pass the thumbnailimageurl into jquery to show in carousel slideshow?

Comment: @Josephine yes, assuming the carousel takes a list of strings as input, just write the carousel config with PHP. It will then be automatically picked up when the JS is evaluated in the client.

Comment: @gordon, so appreciate your help. is there any example on that one?

Comment: @gordon - seems like i cannot get all images since on webpage it looks empty. xml shows up on source view.

Comment: @Josephine Cant tell without seeing any code. XML in the sourceview sounds like you are passing the XML to the JavaScript instead of just the image strings though. It would be best to address that specific issue in another question. That way you'll likely get more answers. Just make sure you show the code you use to write the config.

Comment: @gordon, wait, i cannot just use the curl code above to get images/urls? i don't pass the xml to javascript. mm. thanks

Comment: @Josephine you *can* use curl if you feel that is easier, but you don't *have* to when you use a stream context. Which of the two you use is completely up to you though. I suggest to make the javascript part into a followup question.